# SWIFT Scrollview en una vista para seleccionar varias imagenes horizontal

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

espero alguien me auxilie, tengo un scrollview para seleccionar una imagen, y como es común pasar la imagen seleccionada a la vista y las demás no se ven, me gustaría tener la colección de imágenes en la misma vista y poder seleccionar una pero que se vayan recorriendo y en el centro que quede la que se va a seleccionar, estas imgenes son pequeñas, yo lo tengo como en la primera foto, pero quiero que se vean como en la segunda, ya intenté cambiar el tamaño del scrollview pero hace cosas raras  y no me selecciona ninguna imagen y se queda en la misma y recorre todas las imágenes.. en fin, quiero que se vea como en la segunda imagen, en la primera me va bien, la verdad no se que este haciendo mal para lograrlo como en la segunda, según yo solo es cambiar el tamaño del scrollview... esta es la foto:

[image: la primer foto me va bien, pero en la segunda no logro comprender como colocarlo tal cual y al seleccionar una imagen que me recorra pero sin que se salga de la vista, un carrusel simple y pequeño...]

este es el código que tengo:

private var instrumentsImagesArray = UIImage

```
    private func carousell() {
    instrumentsImagesArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "keyboard2x"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "guitar"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "drumm"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mic"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tune")]

    instrumentLabelGain = []
    for i in 0..<instrumentsImagesArray.count {
        let instrumentsImageView = UIImageView()
        instrumentsImageView.image = instrumentsImagesArray[i]
        let positionX = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        instrumentsImageView.contentMode =  .scaleAspectFit
        instrumentsImageView.frame = CGRect(x: positionX, y: 15, width: self.scrollImageInstrument.frame.width,
                                                                height: self.scrollImageInstrument.frame.height - 25)

        levelImageVolumeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.scrollImageInstrument.frame.midX + 10,
                                             y: self.scrollImageInstrument.frame.minY - 87, width: 32,
                                             height: 32)

        scrollImageInstrument.contentSize.width = scrollImageInstrument.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        scrollImageInstrument.addSubview(levelImageVolumeLabel)
        scrollImageInstrument.addSubview(instrumentsImageView)
    }
```

Comment: HAs probado ha hacerlo con una collectionView?

Comment: lo voy a intentar, muchas gracias por la sugerencia Sdivmp

Comment: Yo creo que la solución como comenta @Spidvmp es un collection view con pagination y una lógica que haga que cuando haces scroll la imagen que se "pierde" por el borde aparezca al otro lado. Simulando una forma circular. Para esto modifica el array del collection y haz un addCell